How to get sphericity results with Anova() function from Car package
I have an unbalanced dataset (4 groups in total, of which 3 groups consist of 8 rats and one group consists of 7 rats). I want to run a mixed ANOVA (type III) with the Car package. My dataset has 3 factors: Day (10 levels, within-subject factor), Sex (2 levels, between-subject factor) and Group (2 levels, between-subject factor). My dependent variable is Weight.
A subset of my data can be obtained with this code:
weight_gain_SI <- structure(list(Day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), class = "factor"), Rat = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L), levels = c("I0", 
"I1", "I2", "I3", "J0", "J1", "J2", "J3", "K0", "K1", "K2", "K3", 
"L0", "L1", "L3", "M0", "M1", "M2", "M3", "N0", "N1", "N2", "N3", 
"O0", "O1", "O2", "O3", "P0", "P1", "P2", "P3"), class = "factor"), 
    Weight = c(1.015921931, 1.011339093, 1.016291327, 1.019565217, 
    1.046148738, 1.011992005, 1.041567291, 1.023960067, 0.992353905, 
    0.972113503, 0.991992463, 1.00931677, 1.004423273, 0.994209809, 
    1.031988873, 1.036828645, 1.015625, 1.001497006, 1.004291845, 
    1.057726153, 1.04837595, 1.048746996, 1.046019483, 1.010251153, 
    1.024016352, 1.017249877, 1.011802575, 1.044538362, 1.043112513, 
    1.032426778, 1.039370079, 0.995377504, 1.021598272, 0.973646382, 
    0.970652174, 1.002324037, 0.988674217, 0.989778535, 0.988019967, 
    0.985800109, 0.989236791, 0.971267075, 0.996376812, 1.023817625, 
    0.991485014, 0.998609179, 1.053196931, 1.014616935, 0.989021956, 
    1.033798283, 1.065821894, 1.072909468, 1.057329214, 1.06886127, 
    1.017426961, 0.998978028, 1.049285362, 1.027896996, 1.057542263, 
    1.061338941, 1.057880056, 1.061280383, 0.996404725, 0.976781857, 
    0.972208912, 0.95923913, 0.983067729, 0.987341772, 0.97955707, 
    1.008319468, 0.980338613, 0.995596869, 0.995760716, 0.979296066, 
    1.040830214, 0.982629428, 0.98922114, 1.028132992, 1.047883065, 
    1.027944112, 1.058476395, 1.093980993, 1.098479613, 1.080672846, 
    1.095398052, 1.038954382, 1.059785386, 1.057663874, 1.055257511, 
    1.08289987, 1.069751139, 1.078103208, 1.063334474), Sex = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), levels = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
    Group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Control ", "Stress "
    ), class = "factor"), line_group = c("Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", 
    "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", 
    "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", 
    "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", 
    "Male Stress ", "Female Control ", "Female Control ", "Female Control ", 
    "Female Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", 
    "Male Control ", "Female Control ", "Female Control ", "Female Control ", 
    "Female Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", 
    "Male Control ", "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", 
    "Female Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", 
    "Male Stress ", "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", 
    "Female Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", 
    "Female Control ", "Female Control ", "Female Control ", 
    "Female Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", 
    "Male Control ", "Female Control ", "Female Control ", "Female Control ", 
    "Female Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", 
    "Male Control ", "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", 
    "Female Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", 
    "Male Stress ", "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", "Female Stress ", 
    "Female Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", "Male Stress ", 
    "Female Control ", "Female Control ", "Female Control ", 
    "Female Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", 
    "Male Control ", "Female Control ", "Female Control ", "Female Control ", 
    "Female Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", "Male Control ", 
    "Male Control ")), row.names = c(NA, -93L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

My code looks like this:

weight_gain_SI$Sex <- as.factor(weight_gain_SI$Sex)
weight_gain_SI$Group <- as.factor(weight_gain_SI$Group)
weight_gain_SI$Day <- as.factor(weight_gain_SI$Day)
weight_gain_SI$Rat <- as.factor(weight_gain_SI$Rat)

model  <- lm(Weight ~ Sex*Group*Day, data = weight_gain_SI,
         contrasts=list(Sex=contr.sum,Group=contr.sum, Day=contr.sum))

Anova(model, type=3)


When I run this code, I do not get the Mauchly's test result and the Geisser - Greenhouse or Huynh - Feldt results. What code do I need to run in order to obtain these results?
I also tried to run this code:

new_anova <- Anova(model,
               idata=data.frame(Day),
               idesign = ~Day,
               type="III")
summary(new_anova, multivariate=FALSE)


but it gave me this output:
    Sum Sq               Df            F value             Pr(>F)         
 Min.   :  0.0005   Min.   :  1.00   Min.   :     0.2   Min.   :0.0000000  
 1st Qu.:  0.0458   1st Qu.:  1.00   1st Qu.:    28.4   1st Qu.:0.0000000  
 Median :  0.1033   Median :  9.00   Median :    99.1   Median :0.0000000  
 Mean   : 38.6102   Mean   : 34.44   Mean   :113348.9   Mean   :0.1247278  
 3rd Qu.:  0.2707   3rd Qu.:  9.00   3rd Qu.:   609.4   3rd Qu.:0.0000229  
 Max.   :346.0971   Max.   :270.00   Max.   :904371.0   Max.   :0.9977311  
                                     NA's   :1          NA's   :1    

which is very different from the outputs I saw online that people obtained with that code. I would want an output that looks like this (screenshot from an online website, link: https://www.crumplab.com/rstatsforpsych/repeated-measures-anova.html):
output that someone else got with the same code
Can someone please help me with this issue? Many thanks in advance!

?car::Anova says: "For objects of class "Anova.mlm", there is also a summary method, which provides much more detail than the print method about the MANOVA, including traditional mixed-model univariate F-tests with Greenhouse-Geisser and Huynh-Feldt corrections." Suggesting these tests are available for MANOVAs, not for the lm object that you are passing. Your own links suggest using aov() instead of lm().

Good point. Only if the mlm object type of an Anova object were being examined would you need a test of sphericity.

It's not spelled "Car", it's spelled "car" which is important with R package names.
install.packages("car")
help.search("Greenhouse")
#results in another window ....
DescTools::Eps      Greenhouse-Geisser And Huynh-Feldt Epsilons

So nothing in the car package docmentation has reference to that sphericity test but another of my installed packages did have reference to an "Eps" function.
If you look at the help page for car::Anova you see this in the Authors section:

John Fox jfox@mcmaster.ca; the code for the Mauchly test and Greenhouse-Geisser and Huynh-Feldt corrections for non-spericity in repeated-measures ANOVA are adapted from the functions stats:::stats:::mauchly.test.SSD and stats:::sphericity by R Core; summary.Anova.mlm and print.summary.Anova.mlm incorporates code contributed by Gabriel Baud-Bovy.

Apropos my emphasis on spelling, it's only critical in coding, but I do note that "sphericity" is misspelled in that text. There is however an extra stats::: in the citation to the mauchly.test.SSD. So that deserves a correction request to John Fox.(I'll also suggest that "Greenhouse", "Geisser" and "Mauchly" be added as keywords for the Anova help page.
If you want the code you can use:
stats:::sphericity
function (object, Sigma = diag(nrow = p), T = Thin.row(Proj(M) - 
    Proj(X)), M = diag(nrow = p), X = ~0, idata = data.frame(index = seq_len(p))) 
{
    p <- ncol(object$SSD)
    if (missing(T)) {
        if (inherits(M, "formula")) 
            M <- model.matrix(M, idata)
        if (inherits(X, "formula")) 
            X <- model.matrix(X, idata)
        if (Rank(cbind(M, X)) != Rank(M)) 
            stop("X does not define a subspace of M")
    }
    Psi <- T %*% Sigma %*% t(T)
    B <- T %*% object$SSD %*% t(T)
    pp <- nrow(T)
    U <- solve(Psi, B)
    sigma <- Tr(U)/pp/object$df
    lambda <- Re(eigen(U, only.values = TRUE)$values)
    GG.eps <- sum(lambda)^2/sum(lambda^2)/pp
    n <- object$df
    HF.eps <- ((n + 1) * pp * GG.eps - 2)/(pp * (n - pp * GG.eps))
    return(list(GG.eps = GG.eps, HF.eps = HF.eps, sigma = sigma))
}
<bytecode: 0x5616d7fb09d8>
<environment: namespace:stats>

And for further expansion of this help-search investigation, I tried:
help.search("sphericity")

and get
Help pages:
performance::check_factorstructure      Check suitability of data for Factor Analysis (FA) with Bartlett's Test of Sphericity and KMO
performance::check_sphericity       Check model for violation of sphericity
stats::mauchly.test     Mauchly's Test of Sphericity

Which meant that ?mauchly should have brought up the mauchly.test help page from the stats package as an auto-complete option.
